# Speedy meetings for the entire organization?

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-apps

Is is possible to set the default setting for all users to have speedy meetings enabled? This setting changes meetings to last 50 minutes versus an hour. I've set it up on my own account, but would like to see how I can manage it for my team.

https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/83117?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like this is possible with the Calendar API. What you can modify can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/settings).

I'd recommend testing with the `defaultEventLength` id though as it seems like it'll accept any positive number and you may be able to set this as 50 minutes for your users.